# Eigen set to zero all values close to zero

Tags: c++, matrix, zero, eigen3

Let's say I have an Eigen matrix with many values that are close to zero:

```
M = 
[          0,           0,           0,           0]
[  0.0045549,   -0.048242,   0.0069165,  9.7007e-07]
[   0.048251,    0.004541,  -0.0046149,  1.8313e-06]
```

What is the most efficient way to write a function that takes this matrix and sets to 0 the values that are close to zero within a certain tolerance, e.g.:

```
setAlmostZeroToZero(M, 1e-4) = 
[          0,           0,           0,           0]
[  0.0045549,   -0.048242,   0.0069165,           0]
[   0.048251,    0.004541,  -0.0046149,           0]
```

Comment: `M.unaryExpr([](double x){return (abs(x)<1e-4)?0.:x;})` shouldn't be too bad, your compiler is likely to vectorize it.

Comment: Or something like `(M.abs()<1e-4).select(0.,M)` (untested) https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#a65e78cfcbc9852e6923bebff4323ddca

Comment: @MarcGlisse the second only works in the Array domain: https://godbolt.org/z/MbPBqV